# Remote removing admin rights for application

Tags: android

How can i remove administration rights (DevicePolicyManager.removeActiveAdmin(Component name)) of application from another application. In particular, i've got working code for uninstalling application from other application:

```
Intent removerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
removerIntent.setData(packageUri);
startActivity(removerIntent);
```

but target app has admin rights, and i wonder - can i remove them from the same method, where i remove the app?

Comment: You can't disable administrator rights from other application.

Comment: But you can show the information dialog (to inform the user to disable admin rights).

Comment: Yeah) But my boss want to do this with secrecy.

Comment: Android does not allow disabling admin rights from other apps (for security)

Comment: I have checked android source and i concluded that only this same uid and system can disable admin rights. If the target app is your app you can set this same sharedUserId and try using removeActiveAdmin again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't disable administrator rights from other application.

But you can show the information dialog (to inform the user to disable admin rights). And start device admin settings using intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$DeviceAdminSettingsActivity"));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

It works for me.